Fetch without Rebuild next js
I use NextJS and I'm trying to make a static site with Wordpress as a backend, I managed to deploy my site with GitLab which deploys to an FTP server.
My problem is that I have to rebuild each time to change the data
I don't want to use useEffect because it's not great for SEO, and I can't use getStaticProps with a NextJS 14 app
async function fetchData() {
  const res = await fetch("fetchUrl", {
    next: { revalidate: 60 }, // Revalidation ISR (par exemple, toutes les 60 secondes)
  });
  if (!res.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch posts");
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await fetchData();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-red-500">data wordpress and deploy ci/cd</div>
      <pre>{data.acf.titre}</pre>
    </>
  );
}

I would like my page to fetch by refreshing the deployed site in the correct way without affecting SEO or performance.

From next.js docs:

If you are not using any dynamic functions anywhere else in this route, it will be prerendered during next build to a static page. The data can then be updated using Incremental Static Regeneration.

Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) enables you to:

Update static content without rebuilding the entire site
Reduce server load by serving prerendered, static pages for most requests
Ensure proper cache-control headers are automatically added to pages
Handle large amounts of content pages without long next build times

Example
interface Post {
  id: string
  title: string
  content: string
}
 
// Next.js will invalidate the cache when a
// request comes in, at most once every 60 seconds.
export const revalidate = 60
 
// We'll prerender only the params from `generateStaticParams` at build time.
// If a request comes in for a path that hasn't been generated,
// Next.js will server-render the page on-demand.
export const dynamicParams = true // or false, to 404 on unknown paths
 
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  let posts: Post[] = await fetch('https://api.vercel.app/blog').then((res) =>
    res.json()
  )
  return posts.map((post) => ({
    id: post.id,
  }))
}
 
export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  let post = await fetch(`https://api.vercel.app/blog/${params.id}`).then(
    (res) => res.json()
  )
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{post.content}</p>
    </main>
  )
}

Here's how this example works:

During next build, all known blog posts are generated (there are 25 in this example)
All requests made to these pages (e.g. /blog/1) are cached and instantaneous
After 60 seconds has passed, the next request will still show the cached (stale) page
The cache is invalidated and a new version of the page begins generating in the background
Once generated successfully, Next.js will display and cache the updated page
If /blog/26 is requested, Next.js will generated and cached this page on-demand

Edit
export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2' }, { id: '3' }]
}
 
// Three versions of this page will be statically generated
// using the `params` returned by `generateStaticParams`
// - /pages/1
// - /pages/2
// - /pages/3
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const { id } = params
  // ...
}


how do I pass the data from my page id 2 to my home page because this is for posts and not page data? THANKS

What do you mean? You can use this example on your homepage

I don't want to map but retrieve the data from my wordpress from my page id 2 and not from the params

What's "page id 2"?  You can edit the generateStaticParams to not map the response. It was just used as an example

page id 2 is my route for fetch myUrl/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/2 but Im not sure this solution is the better

Check my edited answer. generateStaticParams needs to map all the available page-id's to statically generate routes at build time.

There might me two possible solutions for your problem:
1- Add a tag in fetch to re-validate path on specific operations ie. when you update your data call that particular tag to revalidate it.
-> fetch(https://..., { next: { tags: ['collection'] } })
2- By default NextJs 14 caches your fetch response, so you can make fetch request every time you hit the API. So disable cache by adding this.
->fetch(https://..., { cache: 'force-cache' | 'no-store' })
Source - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch

force cache not work and no-store put old data I want to fetch a page and not posts
and if I change my wordpress data it changes on the deployed site but I can't find any solution

@Ben Understood i have a idea but i dont know is its the best approach out there:
use this to run a function on window reload->
window.onload = function() {
yourFunctionToFetchData();
};
And then make this function in a another js/ts file which should be "client-side" and there define this function and make api request to fetch latest data.
Let me know if any more doubts.
